# How to append so called hints to oracle sql using spring data jpa specification. Any alternate is also okay

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We designed api to use spring data specification.
We are advised to use index hints in sql to get better results.
Any advice on how to do it without lot of code changes.

We find that `EntityManager` `createQuery` can be used to achieve the desired result.
However this will make us rewrite the entire code that is now written using spring jpa specification.
while spring jpa specification is super helpful in creating dynamic predicates and combining them, this limitation is bit sad.
I would like to know any better approach to achieve the appending of hints as comments to sql statement.

Example : `select /* USE_CONCAT INDEX(table idx_column1 )*/ from table where condtion ...`